# The immunity tag is scoped for a specific subset of its topic

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retagging

The [immunity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immunity) tag info says

> Immunity to civil or criminal liability conferred to an individual by virtue of an office.

However, this is a group of specific types of immunity, including parliamentary immunity and judicial immunity.

We already have a tag separately for diplomatic immunity, [diplomatic-immunity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diplomatic-immunity) which is also strictly a subset of the questions that are covered by the above description, and therefore by that tag also.

There are many other types of immunity that have nothing to do with holders of an office, and for which we have questions already on the site that are not tagged appropriately (nobody has created the specific tag, and the general tag cannot be used according to its description, so either it is not tagged or uses some related tag like [liability](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liability)).

The solution requires three things:

1. Creation of new tag(s) specific to the types of immunity featured in questions which currently are tagged with [immunity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immunity). Judicial immunity for judges and lawyers, parliamentary immunity (potentially with related tag for parliamentary privilege) and similar for elected officials, sovereign immunity for both sovereign states and heads of government not already covered by other immunity.
2. Retagging of those questions with the appropriate specific type.
3. Editing of the tag info to an appropriate general description, and directions to use one of the more specific tags if this is available.

A general [immunity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immunity) tag info should read

> For questions about immunity from civil or criminal liability conferred on a natural or legal person.

Separately, questions where a further immunity is a topic and are not already tagged as above, need tags created for them.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this has taken a while!

Would it not be a solution to re-scope the current [immunity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immunity) tag to the proposal at the end?

I'm unsure of the need for the more specific kinds of immunity, seeing as we currently only have 12 questions tagged [immunity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immunity) and 5 with [diplomatic-immunity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diplomatic-immunity)

Comment: That still leaves us in the *de facto* *status quo*, and if there are only twelve questions that would be under the same new tag, why not get ahead of the game to do it properly? Hence the request as made rather than only partial change.

Comment: The main issue is that creating new tags only works (properly) if there are questions to which they can be immediately applied; tags with no questions are periodically deleted. Perhaps those which we can apply to existing questions can be created, and then in the tag excerpt for [tag:immunity] ask users to consider more specific tag where possible.

Comment: Well, that would be exactly what I suggested, 1 2 3.

Comment: Sure, that sounds fine. I believe you can already edit the [tag:immunity] tag wiki and excerpt; and then retagging anything that needs anything more specific, as well. I'm currently going through review queues but I'm happy for you to put in the proposed edits.